# Ignoring the first duplicate in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, duplicates

I'm quite new to SQL but I have managed to get my select statement to works it shows fullpath, MD5checksum and the number of times that MD5cheksum appears. Now I want to get it so that the code ignores the first time an MD5checksum appears.

here is the my current statement;

```
SELECT F.Fullpath 
    ,F.MD5Checksum
    ,[tbl.Finance].count 
FROM [tbl.Finance] F
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MD5Checksum
    ,count(*) as Count 
    FROM [tbl.Finance]
    GROUP BY MD5Checksum
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) [tbl.Finance] 
    ON F.MD5Checksum = [tbl.Finance].MD5Checksum
ORDER BY MD5Checksum
```

if I can get any help that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
  F.Fullpath 
 ,F.MD5Checksum
 ,[tbl.Finance].count
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F.MD5Checksum ORDER BY F.MD5Checksum) rn
FROM [tbl.Finance] F
inner join 
(select 
 MD5Checksum
,count(*) as Count 
 from [tbl.Finance]
 group by MD5Checksum
 having Count(*) > 1
 ) [tbl.Finance] on F.MD5Checksum = [tbl.Finance].MD5Checksum)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn>1
```

Comment: sorry i'm just getting --------                                              Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'tbl.Finance'. ----------- do I need to edit this in some way. Thanks

Comment: @AdamWadsworth I had an extra comma,try it now

Comment: I am now getting this -----Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: ok I've fixed the above error I was adding an extra order by function which I didn't need. but now i'm getting------Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Ambiguous column name 'MD5Checksum'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Ambiguous column name 'MD5Checksum'.

Comment: Thank you that has fixed it  and thanks for helping me.